# 'clang' vs. 'gcc' vs. 'cpp' Binaries

Tags: gcc

On MacOS 14.2, typing either '`clang --version`' or '`gcc --version`' (or even '`cpp --version`') returns the same:

```
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

What is the difference between `cpp`, `gcc`, `clang`? '`ls -la /usr/bin`' tells me at least none of them are symlinks.

Comment: Removed the [link to the training](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-s096-introduction-to-c-and-c-january-iap-2013/resources/mit6_s096_iap13_lec1/) , it was simply the inspiration for the question (see example starting slide 28 of PDF). I believe the reasons are to demonstrate the generality of compilers, examine the pre-processing step, as well as isolate the use of macros for beginning students.

Comment: the motivation to this question was a [simpler question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77706797/22673230) resolved on SO, which may add a little context to this very broad prompt. i thought i had found a difference in the behaviors of the listed binaries, but i was using `gcc`/`clang` incorrectly. i think the answers  found here could still be useful to future users.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905104/compiling-without-main-function-macos might help with the other question. `gcc -nostartfiles -Wl,-e,_mymain main.c` compiles and links (and can be successfully executed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regard to, *"What is the difference between cpp and these other binaries (gcc and clang)? 'ls -la /usr/bin' clearly demonstrates none of them are symlinks."*

`/usr/bin/clang`, `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/cpp` are hardlinks to the same binary. An `ls -il` of the three will show the same inode number, an equivalent link-count (e.g. 76) and a `256shasum` hash for each with the same value.

```
$ ls -il /usr/bin/clang /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/cpp    
1152921500312436371 -rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167136 Dec  2 02:00
  /usr/bin/clang
1152921500312436371 -rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167136 Dec  2 02:00
  /usr/bin/cpp
1152921500312436371 -rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167136 Dec  2 02:00
 /usr/bin/gcc

$ shasum -a 256 /usr/bin/clang /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/cpp    
ca08407ee7e1a179d096fe27b8edef2a24cb33402f6338654e1b25589df9a4ba
  /usr/bin/clang
ca08407ee7e1a179d096fe27b8edef2a24cb33402f6338654e1b25589df9a4ba
  /usr/bin/gcc
ca08407ee7e1a179d096fe27b8edef2a24cb33402f6338654e1b25589df9a4ba
  /usr/bin/cpp
```

Thus, when executing any of these, the name chosen for execution affords the option of allowing different behavior for the same file.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about hardlinks. Is it documented anywhere what the different execution behaviors are for these particular ones (clang, gcc, cpp)? A totally tangential question this raises for me is how to generally inspect the execution properties of a hardlink?

Comment: The program is able to determine which was called and then choose different behavior based on invocation. The program could be called `foo` and invoked as `foo -clang` and `foo -gcc` instead of being hard links and perform the same operation @shea

Comment: @shea There's no way to inspect it. It's just part of the code of the program. It checks what name it was run with, and adjusts its behavior accordingly. The actual software is `clang`, but when it sees that its name is `gcc` it implements parameter processing compatible with GCC.

Comment: trying to synthesize these helpful replies. so, the file corresponding to inode `1152921500312436371` (as in JRFerguson's answer, I assume this is the true `clang` executable) is taking 'gcc', 'clang', or 'cpp' as a parameter (passed in by calling) to determine behavior? thus presumably `cpp` in my original question is just `clang` with some special configuration since i am calling it using `cpp`?

Comment: @shear no - look at unix tutorials for links - they are all the same file and are all the true executable - a Unix program knows what it was called as and then can choose what to do. However in this case only use this file as clang or C++ - if you want gcc install a gcc as the compiler behaves differently.

Comment: ***what?*** Is everyone here in agreement that the "behavior" of a compiler can be altered through a hard link?  What sort of behavior are we talking about?

Comment: at least concerning my original question, i simply [misunderstood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77706797/22673230) the behavior of `gcc`/`clang`/`cpp` @Seamus. i am interested in the answers to these more general questions though

Comment: @shea: Yes, hopefully we'll learn something in a follow-up.

Comment: @seamus Having one binary hardlinked under different names (and having slightly different behavior depending on the value of $0) is not uncommon (historically, it helped to save disk space used by the OS). `more`/`less` are often hardlinked, also `rm`/`unlink` or the various versions of `grep` (`ls -il /usr/bin/{bz,}{e,f,}grep`). Run `ls -il /usr/bin | sort | fgrep -v 'r-x   1'` for the whole list.

Comment: In nohillsides comment more/less and rm/unlink both links behave the same whilst the grep ones show one executable behaving in different ways.

Comment: @Seamus re "What sort of behavior are we talking about?" - it could be anything, it does not even have to be related like the grep ones are related. But if they differed it would probably be a bad design. Theoretically all the programs in /usr/bin (if not bin) could have been compiled into one executable and called by different names. You could consider the code implemntation using a large if/else on the name the executable was called as.

Comment: @nohillside: Hmm - yeah... "intercepting" a call and changing "behavior" based on the value of `$0` would work. But I'm still surprised that Apple's compiler is so similar to `gcc` it could be handled in this fashion. So... is the ***true*** compiler on Mac `gcc` or `clang`? Or, are you saying that Apple just ripped off `gcc`, and put a new name on it?

Comment: @seamus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang might help to throw some light on this. The similarity is intentional.

Comment: @nohillside: That's good information - thanks. I suppose *the thing* I have an issue with is Apple's *policy* wrt "open-source software". They're OK with taking it, and using it, but when it comes to giving something back (required under GPL v3)), they pull up short. Their opacity upsets me - in documentation, and in open-source. They are the **world's biggest company**, but that doesn't mean they must also be the **world's most opaque software publisher**.

Comment: @seamus Which (GNU) software provided as part of macOS is under GPL v3?

Comment: @nohillside: Nothing... that's my point.

Comment: @seamus Not sure a company has to adhere to a license which doesn’t apply as it doesn’t distribute any products licensed with it (meaning they don’t take anything which would require “giving back”). Sure, it might be beneficiary if Apple would contribute to OSS (like Google does), but that doesn’t seem to be their intention.

Comment: @nohillside: That's one way to look at it (*"Not sure a company has to adhere to a license which doesn’t apply as it doesn’t distribute any products licensed with it"*), except for the fact that they stopped distributing these products as soon as the license changed.  But you have your pro-Apple view, and I know you'll stick with it. Me? I love their hardware, but as far as the company and their policies go... I think they're greedy and abusive to their customers.     Merry Christmas :)